Keeping a running total of quantites while matching items and dates within a range
I'm attempting to match job lines to purchase orders on items within a date range while tracking the available quantity of the items.
If I have three dataframes:
    joblines = pd.DataFrame({
        'order': ['1-1', '1-1', '2-1', '3-1'],
        'item': ['A1','A2','A1', 'A1'],
        'startdate':[pd.Timestamp('2024-7-25'), pd.Timestamp('2024-7-25'), pd.Timestamp('2024-8-05'), pd.Timestamp('2024-9-02')],
        'qty': [1, 2, 3, 3]
        })

    items = pd.DataFrame({
        'item': ['A1', 'A2'],
        'onhand':[2, 2]
    })

    polines = pd.DataFrame({
        'po':['1','2','3'],
        'item':['A1', 'A2', 'A1'],
        'qty': [1, 1, 5],
        'reqdate': [pd.Timestamp('2024-7-23'), pd.Timestamp('2024-7-26'), pd.Timestamp('2024-9-01')]
    })

I'm attempting to get here:



Order
Item
Start
Qty
PO
Req
Notes




1-1
A1
2024-07-25
1
1
2024-07-23
OnHand


1-1
A2
2024-07-25
2
2
2024-07-26
OnHand


2-1
A1
2024-08-05
3


No Available PO


3-1
A2
2024-09-02
3
3
2024-09-01




So the first two lines are covered by existing quantities, the third line has no associated purchase order (+- 5 days between start and req), and the last line has a purchase order coming in to cover its quantity.
Is this possible using pandas?

The lack of common unique keys across the tables made me avoid a SQL-join like solution.
There is also the open ended question of what happens when an item in joblines matches to multiple purchase orders in polines using the 5 day datediff rule. I simply opted to take the first available.
joblines[["PO", "Req", "Notes"]] = ""
inventory = {x["item"]: x["onhand"] for x in items.to_dict(orient="records")}


def match_po(item, start_d):
    po_items = polines[polines["item"] == item]

    if len(po_items) < 1:
        return (-1, -1)
    po_items["datediff"] = po_items["reqdate"].apply(lambda x: abs((x - start_d).days))
    po_items = po_items[po_items["datediff"] <= 5]

    if len(po_items) > 0:
        index = po_items.index[0]
        po, reqdate = (po_items.loc[index, "po"], po_items.loc[index, "reqdate"])
        polines.drop(index, inplace=True)
        return (po, reqdate)
    return (-1, -1)


def check_items(x):
    item, order_q, start_d = x["item"], x["qty"], x["startdate"]

    # match po
    po, reqdate = match_po(item, start_d)
    if po != -1:
        x["PO"] = po
        x["Req"] = reqdate
    else:
        x["Notes"] = "No Available PO"

    # check if item on hand
    if item in inventory:
        q = inventory[item]
        if q > 0:
            if q >= order_q:
                inventory[item] -= order_q
                x["Notes"] = "OnHand"

    return x


joblines = joblines.apply(check_items, axis=1)

